# OpenWrite UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I am working on a desktop application that internally creates a `StringBuilder` that errors get appended to and ultimately gets written to a txt file.

I get an exception that says 'Access to the path 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\test_dir\5_hundred_thousand_rows_Logs.txt' is denied.'

Below is the code that performs the creation of the .txt file.  The exception catches on the `File.OpenWrite(tempfile))` line

```cs
string tempfile="C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\test_dir\\5_hundred_thousand_rows_Logs.txt";

using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(tempfile))//exception here
{
    string data = logFileContent.ToString();
    Byte[] filecontent = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(data);
    fileStream.Write(filecontent, 0, filecontent.Length);
}

 Process.Start(tempfile);
```

I have double checked and the tempfile does indeed have the file extension and is not attempting to create a directory.

I've tried wrapping the `using` statement with the following to attempt to "grant" access but to no avail:

```cs
var permissionSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
var writePermission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess, Path.GetDirectoryName(tempfile));
writePermission.Demand();
permissionSet.AddPermission(writePermission);
FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(Path.GetDirectoryName(tempfile));
if (permissionSet.IsSubsetOf(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.PermissionSet))
{
   // using statement
}
```

I am wanting this desktop application to be able to be handed to anyone and they be able to use this without having the user deal with folder permissions or something.  Granted I'm really only expecting it to try to access MyDownloads, MyDocuments, directories on flash drives or other similar devices.

I would greatly appreciate any help provided.

EDIT:

It appears that this may be a Windows issue. The file is set to readonly in its properties (was not this way originally), and attempting to set the file as not readonly doesn't work as Windows apparently just resets it back to readonly.  However if the file is not in a folder and is just sitting on the bare drive (such as a different drive eg: D:/5_hundred_thousand_rows_Logs.txt) it seems to work just fine.  If there's a programmatic way to get around this I would appreciate it, but if this is a Windows issue this may require making this a different question.

Comment: How are you running this?  Are you the "me" user?

Comment: @Crowcoder I am signed into that account, yes, and trying to run this.  I'm even trying to debug it via VS2019 and I keep running into this

Comment: Windows does not arbitrarily change the read-only flag on files. Something else is doing that.

Comment: @IanKemp anything in a folder on my machine, say Documents\TestProject\*.txt has the readonly attribute checked.  unchecking, clicking apply/ok, and then immediately opening the properties back up on that file shows that the readonly attribute is rechecked.  if this is not a Windows issue, what could it be?  don't just make a comment without any kind of suggestion or possible explanation.  it's unhelpful.

Comment: "if this is not a Windows issue, what could it be?" Why don't you, you know, **try checking what's running on your machine that could be doing this**? I had hoped my comment would prompt you to do so but apparently you're not interest in doing your own troubleshooting, you just want solutions handed to you on a platter.

Comment: @IanKemp  I have looked, and currently there's nothing on my machine that jumps out as being something that could do this.  I've checked antivirus and a number of other options, and nothing so far seems to be specifically causing this.  Also your statement of essentially Windows doesn't do this is false.  there have been cases like this in the past.  2 years ago Windows 10 had this issue (I've checked those suggested solutions to no effect).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openwrite?view=net-5.0) the exception is thrown when you don't have the permissions, or the file is readonly.

To test if you don't have permissions, try and run your application as administrator. To verify the second case, right click the file in explorer, choose properties, and make sure it's not readonly.

Besides that string `tempfile="C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\test_dir\\5_hundred_thousand_rows_Logs.txt";` is a weird path, because it's using the user `me` which definitelly doesn't exist on every machine. If you like to get the documents folder of the current user you can use: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);` This will create the correct path for you.

Comment: the path is "edited" so that the actual user account is "hidden" and this is for testing purposes.  the actual path is obtained using a different method which accurately obtains the path+filename, however it appears that the it may be a Windows issue.  the file is set to readonly, and attempting to set the file as not readonly doesn't work as Windows apparently just resets it back to readonly.